Why does TypeScript narrow a type for some const declarations but not others?
UPDATED QUESTION (single primary question)
Given the code snippet below, why is the type narrowed when declaring a const to be Version but not for one which is declared as number?
type Version = 1 | 2 | 3;
const v: Version = 3;
if (v === 2) console.log('v equals 2'); // Fails compilation with "This comparison appears to be unintentional
                                        // because the types '3' and '2' have no overlap."
const n: number = 3;
if (n === 2) console.log('n equals 2'); // No compile error

ORIGINAL POST
Given the code snippet below:

Why does the first comparison (v > 2) pass compilation but not the last (v === 2)?
Why does the compile error for (v === 2) say ...types '3' and '2'... rather than ...types 'Version' and '2'?

type Version = 1 | 2 | 3;

const v: Version = 3;

if (v > 2) console.log('v is greater than 2');

if (v === 3) console.log('v equals 3');

if (v === 2) console.log('v equals 2'); // Fails compilation with "This comparison appears to be unintentional 
                                        // because the types '3' and '2' have no overlap."


Yet another over-inference by TypeScript. Apparently it ignores your Version annotation and infers from const-ness of v that it's of type 3, not Version, only checking that 3 is assignable to Version.

• Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." • TypeScript has assignment narrowing so v is of type 3. That's the key to answering both questions, but which one is the question you want to ask here?

@STerliakov it's more of an under-done example. Works fine if the code was close to real: Playground Link But the example is just not real by specifying a constant value.

@jcalz I'm looking for an answer about how the TypeScript compiler handles comparisons for numeric literal union types and am giving two subquestions in order to clarify. Personally I think the question would be less clear if I left out one of them.

@Christian AFAIK the compiler doesn't currently implement the required arithmetic logic for type comparisons in expressions that use inequality operators (e.g. >) — so you could substitute any number type in an inequality operation and the compiler would permit it. However, arithmetic isn't required for the compiler to model strict equality comparisons of types.

^ The reason why the compiler permits strict equality comparisons of two literals is something I don't understand (because it can be reduced to a boolean literal — which means that the conditional and its associated block statement should either be run unconditionally if true or removed if false).

^ In JS, constants can't be reassigned, and numbers are immutable, so the compiler would be doing you a disservice (failing its primary job of supporting type safety) if it didn't narrow assignments of numeric literals to constants. You can use a const assertion if you feel the need to suppress this behavior.

The behavior of > and the behavior of === are essentially independent (the latter is not a numeric operator per se) so this really feels like two different questions in one. If you want to keep them both here, that's your prerogative, but it invites answers where someone addresses one but not the other (the answer below doesn't seem to tell you anything about > and why it doesn't care about "overlap"). If this gets edited to ask a single narrow-scope question I'll revisit. Otherwise, good luck!

@jcalz fair enough, I'll try and narrow the question (no pun intended)

^ I meant type assertion in that comment (not const assertion).

See microsoft/TypeScript#16976 for an authoritative answer to this question.

Generally speaking, narrowing tends only to operate by filtering union types. In
type Version = 1 | 2 | 3;
const v: Version = 3;
((v));
//^? const v: 3

TypeScript performs assignment narrowing on v from the union type 1 | 2 | 3 to just those members assignable to the initializer. That's 3, so v is seen as having the type 3 from then on.
On the other hand,
const n: number = 3;
((n));
//^? const n: number

no useful narrowing is performed. The type number is not a union. If you had something like
const sn: string | number = 3;
((sn));
//^? const sn: number

then you'd see narrowing from string | number to number, because 3 is assignable to number but not string.

So why doesn't narrowing happening for non-union types? Well, the obvious and unhelpful answer is that it hasn't been implemented. According to this comment in microsoft/TypeScript#16976,

Currently there's no logic in effect for "narrowing" of non-unions.

But the actual reason seems to be that it would be more complicated and difficult to do. For example in there I've linked to a relevant comment in microsoft/TypeScript#8513:

The question of narrowing non-union types on assignment is one that we're still thinking about. It gets somewhat more complicated because [...] when optional properties are involved, the assigned type may actually have fewer members than the declared type. One possible mitigation is to use an intersection of the declared type and the assigned type:
let a: { x?: number, y?: number };
a = { x: 1 };
a;  // Type { x: number, y: number | undefined };


And I've also linked to a relevant issue, microsoft/TypeScript#10065 where it's said that

Continuing to think about this but it'd be very expensive -- we'd be resynthesizing a type [...] after every assignment.

It seems that filtering unions never introduces new types that TypeScript has to track (because the union already contains all the relevant types), but narrowing non-unions will often require TypeScript to synthesize and keep track of new types (like new intersections of the declared type and the assigned type), and this is expensive because it means extra work for every assignment.

Playground link to code

When TypeScript sees const v: Version = 3; it is ignoring Version and inferring the type as the number literal type 3.
If v is 3:

(3 > 2) No errors
(3 === 3) No errors
(3 === 2) Error '3' and '2' have no overlap

In the following example, v is a function parameter inferred as Version, not 3. It works as you would expect, with no errors.
type Version = 1 | 2 | 3;

function test(v: Version) {
  if (v > 2) console.log('v is greater than 2'); // No errors
  if (v === 3) console.log('v equals 3'); // No errors
  if (v === 2) console.log('v equals 2'); // No errors
}

test(3);
// Logs:
// "v is greater than 2" 
// "v equals 3" 

Update: About narrowing
When using const v: Version = 3, TS narrows down Version to 3. Then control flow analysis in each if statement narrows down to never in some cases.
const v: Version = 3;

if (v > 2) {
    type t = typeof v; // 3
}

if (v === 3) {
    type t = typeof v; // 3
}

if (v === 2) {
    type t = typeof v; // never
}

if (v !== 3) {
    type t = typeof v; // never
}

if (v !== 2) {
    type t = typeof v; // 3
}

When using const v: number = 3;, TS DOESN'T narrow down number to 3. Then, control flow analysis cannot narrow down number into a more concrete type.
const v: number = 3;

if (v > 2) {
    type t = typeof v; // number
}

if (v === 3) {
    type t = typeof v; // number
}

if (v === 2) {
    type t = typeof v; // number
}

if (v !== 3) {
    type t = typeof v; // number
}

if (v !== 2) {
    type t = typeof v; // number
}


No. (3 !== 2) gives you types '3' and '2' have no overlap (as expected), and (3 !== 3) works without errors just like (3 === 3). If it is true or false has nothing to do with the error. Is driven by overlap or not overlap.

You are right I can lead to confusion. I have removed it now. Thanks!

OK so the type is "narrowed" to be the literal type 3. But let's say I would declare v as a number i.e. const v: number = 3; then I don't get any compilation errors so now there's no narrowing?

The narrowing that is causing the issue happens in the variable declaration. I have added more details to the answer.

thanks for the explanation. But then why is it narrowing in one case but not the other?

It is just the way the TypeScript team decided to implement this. They look at use cases before implementing a feature, and in this case, they probably determined that when people use number literal types instead of just numbers, they probably really want to narrow down to the exact number literal type. So they made the number literal type more aggressive at narrowing.

I would recommend including the documentation for assignment narrowing. Assignment narrowing works by filtering unions (so 1 | 2 | 3 can be narrowed to 3 but number cannot).

@jcalz so number cannot be narrowed because it's not a union? Conceptually one could view it as the union of all possible numbers.

Conceptually, sure, but it doesn't happen. See ms/TS#16976 and the comments and links within. Note that you've already accepted this answer but it doesn't actually answer your updated question in any authoritative way (it doesn't even mention the word "union", nor does it link to any official doc or github or anything like that). I'd be happy to write up an answer, but presumably OP of this answer could go ahead and actually make the answer do this stuff? Not sure how to proceed.

@RemoH.Jansen would you consider updating your answer according to the feedback given by @jcalz?

@jcalz if you write a more clear answer than the accepted one, I'd be happy to accept yours instead.
